# Not deleting for localStorage in a simple reminder

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, local-storage

I'm new to js, and I would really appreciate your help with this problem I'm having.

Trying to delete the selected item from local storage.

I tried these 2 functions:

Deletes the hole list:

```
    $('#delete').on('click', function() {
    var radioButton = $('input[name="checked"]:checked');
    var item = radioButton.parent();

    console.log(TheList);

    item.fadeOut(500, function(){
        var index = item.index();
        TheList.splice(index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem('TaskList', JSON.stringify(TheList));
        item.remove();            

        alert('"' + radioButton.attr('value') + '" was deleted!');

    });
});
```

Deletes it from the list but not from local storage

```
    $('#delete').on('click', function() {
    var radioButton = $('input[name="checked"]:checked');
    var itemName = radioButton.attr('value');
    var item = radioButton.parent();

    item.fadeOut(500, function(){
        item.remove();
        for (var j = 0; j < TheList.length; j++) {
            if (TheList[j].text == itemName) {
                delete TheList[j];
            }
        }
        localStorage.setItem('TaskList', JSON.stringify(TheList));  
    });
});
```

You can try the application here:

http://jsfiddle.net/6LQZm/

Can you please explain what I did wrong and how can it be deleted from localStorage.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the `removeItem()`, To remove the item from localStorage you should use `localStorage.removeItem()` something like this.

```
    item.fadeOut(500, function(){
    localStorage.removeItem(itemName);
```

Comment: wondering if you can help with Phonegap? I'm trying to add PhoneGap - geolocational to this application

Comment: Or maybe I should post this in a new post...!?!

Answer (score 0):

To delete item from array you should use `splice`. However your first code snippet is not reliable because you should not rely on `.index()`. Try this:

```
item.fadeOut(500, function () {
    item.remove();
    for (var j = 0; j < TheList.length; j++) {
        if (TheList[j].text == itemName) {
            TheList.splice(j, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem('TaskList', JSON.stringify(TheList));
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6LQZm/2/